# Deleted the contents of the sd card but made sure to back it up problem

Tags: boot, sd-card, memory

Deleted the contents of the sd card but made sure to back it up but when I am simply try to copy paste the contents it does not work. My raspberry pi does not boot up. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: `copy paste the contents` ... copy and paste what, to where?

Comment: `made sure to back it up` how did you back it up? I suspect you backed up only the boot partition. If you deleted the contents of the SD card, why would the pi boot up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.